# Can I run a decorated function without a decorator functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

If I once used a decorator to my function, how could I run this function alone, without being embedded in a decorator functionality?

For example I have a function `printArg` and it prints an argument. For some usability I needed to "mix it" with `datetime.now()`. For that I wrote a decorator `timeCalled`. Now every time I call `printArg` also a decorator called.

Is there a way to call `printArg` alone, so I wouldn't repeat myself and wrote another "`printArg`" without decorator functionality(`datetime.now()`)?

```py
from datetime import datetime

def timeCalled(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: Function called {func.__name__}')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

@timeCalled
def printArg(arg):
    print(f'Your arg is {arg}')

printArg('Mama')
```

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused with the concept itself, Here try this https://gist.github.com/Zearin/2f40b7b9cfc51132851a#functions-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general way that doesn't rely on implementation details. In this *particular case*, since `func` references the original function in `wrapper` and is in the closure, you can use:

```
printArg.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

To retrieve it.

More generally, it is good practice to use `functools.wraps` when you create the wrapper, this makes the wrapper function "look like" the original function. Moreover, it adds the original function to a `__wrapped__` attribute, so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps

def timeCalled(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: Function called {func.__name__}')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

@timeCalled
def printArg(name):
    print(f'Your arg is {name=}.')
```

In which case, you can use:

```
printArg.__wrapped__
```

Comment: So much answer in a short time span ! I was writing something along the lines of your anwser, so you have my upvote !

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is simply a wrapper function around the decorated function, where the syntax:

```
@timeCalled
def printArg(arg):
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def printArg(arg):
    pass
printArg = timeCalled(printArg)
```

So to achieve to goal of avoiding defining the same function twice, with only one getting decorated, you can define the function once, then call the decorator with the said function passed to it and assign the returning function object to a different name instead:

```
def printArg(arg):
    print(f'Your arg is {name}')

timed_printArg = timeCalled(printArg)
```

So that you can call `timed_printArg('Mama')` for a timed call to `printArg('Mama')`, and call `printArg('Mama')` directly to do it without involving the decorator.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains it perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Give your decorated function a different name. To do this, don't use the `@` notation, but rather:

```
decorated_printArg = timeCalled(printArg)
```

Comment: For my edification, is the method of using functools basically the only and preferred way to run the un-decorated function when the function takes parameters? Or is there any other way to do so that doesn't require a package or isn't overly complex? It seems to me that functools is an after the fact solution. BTW, the functools way is clear and concise, nothing against it. Just wondering if anything can be done to the call: timeCalled(printArg("Hi"))() to avoid the  "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" error.